# Executing `where.exe` within PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm wanting the same functionality within PowerShell that [`where.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753148(v=ws.11).aspx) gives me.

I've tried to find a cmdlet alternative to the standard where executable but can't find anything.

So by default, I resulted into trying to execute the where command within PowerShell but there is an Alias mapped to that command.

```
PS C:\> Get-Command where

CommandType     Name                                           Version    Source
-----------     ----                                           -------    ------
Alias           where -> Where-Object
```

Is there a way to execute `where` within PowerShell or is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: `Get-Command notepad -CommandType Application`

Comment: Get-Command doesn't work for searching

Comment: You can execute where.exe (or any executable) within powershell like so: `& where.exe`, e.g. `& where.exe /R C:\Windows notepad.exe`

Comment: @GarethLyons I do not think the `&` character is need in a case like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not remove the existing `where` alias since this would cause scripts you might use to fail. Instead you could define a new alias for it:

```
Set-Alias -Name "wherecli" -Value "where.exe"
```

And then you can use `wherecli`.

Comment: Ah, yeah good workaround! Is it possible to just set an Alias for a given session? Thanks

Comment: The cmdlet sets the alias only for the current session ;-)

Comment: Just seen that, Doh!

Answer (score 9):

Of course, if you do not wish to remove the `where` alias which points to `Where-Object`, you can type `.exe` (typing `.` followed by the TAB key is enough), as in:

```
where.exe notepad
```

Otherwise, have you tried `Get-Command` (alias `gcm`) with the `-All` parameter (PowerShell 3 and later)? For example:

```
gcm notepad -All
```

on my machine, gives:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     notepad.exe                                        10.0.10... C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe
Application     notepad.exe                                        10.0.10... C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

And it will find PowerShell things as well, as in the example `gcm where -All` which gives:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           where -> Where-Object
Application     where.exe                                          10.0.10... C:\Windows\system32\where.exe
```

---

If you *do* want to remove the "standard" alias, use `Remove-Item alias:where` (can by put in a profile file if you want it done at each start-up of PowerShell).

Comment: :thumbsup:  for noting that you can execute `where` by including the `.exe` extension

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround with just the `Get-ChildItem` and `Where-Object` but this seems slower than `where.exe` but thought I'd list it as depending what you're searching it might be useful.

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\Windows\" -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "notepad.exe"}
```

Comment: Using the Filter param should be quicker than piping to where-object:
`Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\Windows\" -Recurse -File -Filter 'notepad.exe'`
Although not sure how it compares to where.exe